# VirtualBox Mac very slow

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance, speed

my virtual box is really slow and I cannot figure this out.
I am on Mac OS Catalina. My ultimate goal is to run Age of Mythology on my mac so if you know another way I'd be glad.

Thank you for your help! :)

OS: Windows 10 - 64 bits
base Memory: 4096MB

video memory:256MB
Graphic COntroller: VBoxSVGA
Acceleration: 3D

SATA Port 0: VM W10.vdi (Normal, 40.35 GB)
SATA Port 1: [Optical Drive] VBoxGuesAdditions.iso (56.92 MB)

Comment: Why not run it under Boot Camp?

Comment: I d need to have access to my mac OS time to time that s why I m trying to run a VM

Answer (score 1):

While you might be able to troubleshoot and fix your VirtualBox setup, there is another alternative that may work for you.

[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) is available for the [Mac](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS).

> Wine (originally an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator") is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, macOS, & BSD. Instead of simulating internal Windows logic like a virtual machine or emulator, Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly, eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other methods and allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications into your desktop.

Simply put, Wine lets you run Windows programs on non-Windows operating systems.  Be aware that it is not always capable of doing so.  Software run under Wine will have varying degrees of success.  This can range from working perfectly, to not at all, and everywhere in between.

According to [WineDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1979), Age of Mythology has a gold status, which is a high level of compatibility.  Note that those tests were with older versions of Wine and the results might be better, worse, or the same under a different version.

Simply put, there is no harm in trying it under Wine, it may very well run perfectly, or well enough.  If it doesnt, you can report your finding to WineDB.  They may even try to fix the issue.  Worst case, just delete it and try something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Just to know, do you know if it will be possible to use Game Ranger to play online with this solution?